# Site for checking so-dimm memory for MacBooks

Tags: hardware, memory

Is there any website, where I can check which memory (RAM) is suitable for any MacBook or Apple computer?

Answer (score 5):

Apple provide the [technical specifications](http://www.apple.com/support/hardware/) of all their machines since the mid 1990s

Various memory sellers include this information in an easier to access format e.g. [Crucial](http://www.crucial.com/mac/index.aspx)